# Possible bug in FirstPosition

Tags: pattern-matching

When looking for the non-existing `2`, `FirstPosition` returns the default whether or not I specify levelspec:

```
FirstPosition[{1, 1}, 2, a, Heads -> False]
FirstPosition[{1, 1}, 2, a, {1}, Heads -> False]
```

> a
>
> a

When looking for the non-existing `Except[1]`, `FirstPosition` returns the default only when I specify levelspec:

```
FirstPosition[{1, 1}, Except[1], a, Heads -> False]
FirstPosition[{1, 1}, Except[1], a, {1}, Heads -> False]
```

> {}
>
> a

Is it a bug or am I failing to understand `Except`?

Comment: The whole of the expression matches `Except[1]`.  `{}` represents the whole.